# excel macro/methid to copy from one column to another

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have a huge list of certain ID numbers matched with certain locations. I have filtered that large list of ID numbers into a smaller subset and now I need to lcations to match with those. How exactly do I go doing this? My end goal is a pareto chart of the locations. Thanks a lot in advance for your help and I would be happy to answer additional questions if necessary.

Comment: I would look into pivot tables as you should be able to do all the filtering and summing you need.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I am fairly new to excel so I know what pivot tables are/kind of how to make them, but I don't know how to use them in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If list is in the range A1:B10 and the subset is in the range C1:C5 then in D1:

```
=VLOOKUP(C1,$A$1:$B$10,2,FALSE)
```

and so on.